# Calculating predicted probabilities for ordered probit model

Tags: ordered-probit

Trying to figure out how to obtain the values in the table below. For instance, for y=1, I did: 0.75-(-0.50)-15(0.052), and got 0.47. What am I missing? Please help!! Going nuts over this. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The formula is $P(y=1|x)=\Phi(\tau_1-\alpha-\beta x_i)$. Here $\Phi$ denotes the [CDF of standard normal RV](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Normal_distribution#/Cumulative_distribution_function). It doesn't have an explicit integral, so we use so called [Z-Tables](http://www.z-table.com/) for it. Once there, you'll see that the value corresponding to $0.47$ is $0.6808$ (row = $0.4$, column = $0.07$), which is $0.68$ when you take two significant digits.

Comment: If you accept the answer, why don't you accept it? :)